# Array of HEX Values to Decimal

Tags: c

I'm reading in HEX values from a file into an array.

The part of the buffer I'm using is contains 4 bytes in Hex -> CE EE 00 00

```
unsigned int fileLocationOffset = 64;
unsigned char fileSize[4]; //This is actually in a struct. 
                           //Putting here for purposes of this question
unsigned char buff[sizeOfRoot];

fseek(fp, startOfRoot, SEEK_SET); //Seek to point in file fp
fread(buff, 1, sizeOfRoot, fp);   //Save contents to a buffer

//Read in 4 Bytes backwards to put as Big-Endian
for(int z = 31; z > 27; z--){
    fileSize[31 - z] = buff[fileLocationOffset + z];
}

//TEST: Print Values at each element to see if correct
for(int z = 0; z < 4; z++){
  printf("%X ", fileSize[z]);
}
// Output: 0 0 EE CE <- Correct
```

So, I know that my fileSize array contains the correct values, but now I need to convert 0x00EECE to a decimal.

Could somebody please advise how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you read it as a sequence of bytes? Why don't you read it as a single 32-bit unsigned integer? Then you already have the "decimal" value (after some optional bit-fiddling to handle endianness).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is this something I should be doing in the fread? C isn't my strong-point! I read everything into a buffer because the fileSize isn't the only thing I'm extracting. I extract a lot more information from the buffer (most of it is only 1 Bytes so simple to convert to decimal). 

I was hoping to work only with the buffer, but if necessary I guess I could do another seek and fread to put the 4 bytes I need into an unsigned int (if that's what you mean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have the bytes of an int value in big endian order and want to build the value. You could simply place the bytes into an `uint32_t` variable:

```
uint32_t bytes_to_int(unsigned char *bytes) {
    uint32_t val = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        val <<= 8;      //shift 8 positions to the right
        val |= *bytes++;
    }
    return val;
}
```

With it, the following test program:

```
int main() {
    unsigned char foo[] = { 0, 0, 0xee, 0xce };
    unsigned val = bytes_to_int(foo);
    printf("%d - 0x%x\n", val, val);
    return 0;
}
```

output as expected:

```
61134 - 0xeece
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you do with the data?

Concepts like hex and decimal only apply when you print the data.

What is the output of

```
printf("%d", *(int *)filesize);
```

Comment: Yes, the data will be printed. '0x0000EECE' represents the size of a file in bytes. which is what I want to print. 


The output is -823263232, which is completely incorrect. It should be 61134

Answer (score 0):

Your previous comment suggests you are on a little endian machine.

The value in your file is also little endian.

Why do you change your endianess?

See following test program:

```
// big endian
unsigned char fileSize[4] = { 0x0, 0x0, 0xEE, 0xCE };

// little endian
unsigned char fileSize2[4] = { 0xCE, 0xEE, 0x00, 0x00 };

int main(void)
{
    int i;


    // Output: 0 0 EE CE <- Correct
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof fileSize; i++)
        printf("%02x ", fileSize[i]);

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof fileSize2; i++)
        printf("%02x ", fileSize2[i]);

    printf("\n");

    printf("%u\n", *(int *)fileSize);
    printf("%u\n", *(int *)fileSize2);
}
```

Output (on pc):

```
00 00 ee ce
ce ee 00 00
3471704064
61134
```

Comment: Correct. I'm on a little endian machine. I'm analyzing a Disk Image (.dd) which also stores bytes in little endian format. According to some notes that I have, the values have to be converted to big endian in order to get the correct answer.

"Note the little-endian format for the stored bytes on 
the disk, where the least significant byte is stored at the lowest address. This has to be converted to big-endian format and converted to a decimal number."

Comment: I ask again, why you convert the endianess of your data. Your machine is little endian, your data is little endian. When you interpret the memory (casting) as int, the value is correct. Changing the endianess of the data is only required when you use data  from a network (which is defined as big-endian) on a little endian machine. The functions to use in this case are ntohl/ntohs (net to host long /short).

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the data as a single unsigned 32-bit integer and use that almost directly (depending on endianness issues of course).

Perhaps something like this:

```
uint32_t fileSize;
memcpy(&fileSize, buff[fileLocationOffset + 28], 4);
```

Then for the endianness issue, if you're on Linux you could use `be32toh` (see e.g. [this endian manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html)) to convert big-endian to host encoding (and it does nothing if your host system is big-endian):

```
fileSize = be32toh(fileSize);
```

The closest function to this in the Windows API is [`ntohl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069(v=vs.85).aspx), which could be used in a similar way.

---

It's not hard to implement absolute byte-swapping functions, or even macros, for this:

```
inline uint16_t byteswap16(uint16_t value)
{
    return (value & 0xff) << 8 | (value >> 8);
}

inline uint32_t byteswap32(uint32_t value)
{
    return byteswap16(value & 0xffff) << 16 | byteswap16(value >> 16);
}

...
fileSize = byteswap32(fileSize);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Serge Ballesta is correct, however there is one other dirty but short trick to do this.

```
int main() {
char data[]={0xce,0xee,0,0};
int *ptr;
ptr=data;
printf("%d\n",*ptr);
//if you want to store this result
int x=*ptr;
printf("%d\n",x);
return 0;
}
```

This way you won't even have to reverse your bytes.

Output:

> 61134
>
> 61134

Here compiler itself takes care of the endianess